# Firefox radio button focus style

Tags: javascript, css, forms, firefox, radio-button

I am trying to disable the inverted styling of the firefox radio button when on focus(?)

[image: ugly on focus]

to look like the unfocused version below, even when focused. So the transition will be the addition of the check dot in the centre without the semi circles surrounding it changing.

[image: nice not on focus]

I have tried using

```
[type="radio"]:checked {
         -moz-appearance: none; }
```

and

```
 [type="radio"]:focus {
         -moz-appearance: none; }
```

and

```
[type="radio"]:active {
         -moz-appearance: none; }
```

but nothing works. I have searched but have found nothing. 
I wish to do this with CSS.

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/m5FS6/

Comment: In Firebug, I don't see any difference in CSS declarations between the `onfocus` and `onblur` state. Which indicates that it is not controlled by CSS, and thus cannot be changed with it. If you would be interested after all in a simple Javascript solution, just let me know and I'll post the code.

Comment: Ah I see. In that case, please Frank, I would appreciate that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the requested Javascript solution: [**live demo**](http://jsbin.com/xaduxa/1/edit?html,output).

And this is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Demo</title>
<style>
input[type="radio"],
input[type="checkbox"] {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    -moz-appearance: none;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <input type="radio"> First radio
            <br>
        <input type="radio"> Second radio
            <br>
        <input type="checkbox"> First checkbox
            <br>
        <input type="checkbox"> Second checkbox
    </form>
<script>
var radios = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"]');
for (var i=0; i<radios.length; i++) {
    radios[i].onfocus = function() {
        this.blur();
    }
}

var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]');
for (var i=0; i<checkboxes.length; i++) {
    checkboxes[i].onfocus = function() {
        this.blur();
    }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

.
Do be very careful with the property `appearance`. In Chrome25+ (possibly earlier) that makes the inputs in question non-displayed. And Firefox shows illogical behavior, in my opinion. Which generally is not a good sign.

Lastly, you should now add the tag `javascript` to your question, plus the tag `form`. And you should correct it: there is no `elemtent[type="radio"]`, not even an `element[type="radio"]`. In the Fiddle you have the right code, but your question doesn't look very smart the way it is now.

Comment: Thanks Frank, I have edited my question. Yes, I struggle to use the correct terminology in my questions. I was very much 'teach myself now, learn the semantics later', but it's biting me in the butt now.